# audio-context-constructor.js:8 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page

Tags: google-chrome, browser, audiocontext, tone.js

my chrome browser always throw this error, am new at coding and using tone.js 
please can any body help me review my code , and tell me if am doing something wrong

<--/this is my app.js file --/>

```
function sequencer(){
    const kick = new Tone.Player("./drums/PJ - Divine (Kick).wav").toDestination();
    const snare = new Tone.Player("./drums/PJ - Divine (Kick).wav").toDestination();
    let index = 0;

    Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(repeat, "8n");
    Tone.Transport.start();


function repeat(){
    let step = index % 8;
    let kickInputs = document.querySelector(
    `.kick input:nth-child(${step + 1 })`
    );

     let snareInputs = document.querySelector(
    `.snare input:nth-child(${step + 1 })`
    );

     let painoInputs = document.querySelector(
    `.paino input:nth-child(${step + 1 })`
    );
    document.querySelector('kickInput').addEventListener('checked', () => kick.resume());
    document.querySelector('snareInput').addEventListener('checked', () => snare.resume());

    index++;
}
}

 sequencer();
```

```
          <--this is my html file--/>
```

this is the html file, i want the sound to be played when the 
   checkbox/boxes are checked/clicked by a user, but what i do get is the 
    error: audiocontext  is not allowed to start , it's needs to be created or 
     resume ........

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
     <div class="Drum">  
     <div class="Kick"> 
        <h1>DRUM</h1>
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         </div>
        </div>


       <div class="Snare">  
        <h1>SNARE</h1>
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox">
         </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We need to at least have a chance to understand what on earth you are trying to ask. So - please - show what you have tried yourself and add an example of what you expect to come out; short: please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thanks @ Yasen, i really don't think the code is the problem, i just want to  disable the throw error in chrome browser " audio-context-constructor.js:8 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page"

Comment: i think i need to modify the code inorder to use the audiocontext in web browser

Answer (score 0):

@Don Muyi, you’ve probably figured this out already, but your error is arising because Chrome and (I think) many other web browsers will not allow you to start playing a sound without explicit interaction from the user.

So, you should hook a button up to your start() function that the user has to click before your sequencer starts making sound.